# pom.xml input contained no data @

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Java projects not opening and new java projects created are broken.
I'm trying to create a new java project on my Netbeans IDE, however, when a new web app project is created, it is missing folders and the pom.xml is empty

[image]

when I try to resolve the issues this displays in the description

```
1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-readable POM E:\mavenproject1tgd\pom.xml: input contained no data @ 
 for project  at E:\mavenproject1tgd\pom.xml
```

and this displays in the console

```
Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
Non-readable POM E:\mavenproject1tgd\pom.xml: input contained no data @ 
 @ 
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

  The project  (E:\mavenproject1tgd\pom.xml) has 1 error
    Non-readable POM E:\mavenproject1tgd\pom.xml: input contained no data

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: I think this is reated to maven repository. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742407/some-problems-were-encountered-while-building-the-effective-model-for

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the pom.xml is empty, there is nothing inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an elegant fix, however, I was pressed against time so I just uninstalled NetBeans ide and reinstalled Netbeans and Tomcat